# Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, local-storage

I am using react with typescript, I want to set an address to the localStorage every time I click on any of the available addresses text `p`,

```
            <div className="lookup-result-container">
              {requestedAddress.map((address, index) => {
                return (
                  <p onClick={AddRToLocalStorage} key={index}>
                    {query}, {address.line_1}, {address.district},{' '}
                    {address.town_or_city}, {address.country}
                  </p>
                )
              })}
            </div>
```

I have built a function to handle the onClick but it's not working with `event.target.innerHTML` nor with `event.target.value`

```
  const AddRToLocalStorage = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
    localStorage.setItem('addresses', event.target.innerHTML)
  }
```

please note that I don't want to override what is already in the localstorage when I click on address again

Comment: You on `React.MouseEvent` the property for the targetElement ist currentTarget so: `localStorage.setItem('addresses', event.currentTarget.innerHTML)`

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there is no need to use innerHTML.
Just pass the address text to the AddRToLocalStorage function.
Try this way:

```js
const AddRToLocalStorage = (addressText, index): void => {
     // As you need, we can check if there is already exist address in localstorage
     if(!localStorage.getItem(`addresses${index}`)){
        localStorage.setItem(`addresses${index}`, addressText);
     }
};
```

```html
<div className="lookup-result-container">
    {requestedAddress.map((address, index) => {
        const addressText = `${query}, ${address.line_1}, ${address.district},  ${address.town_or_city}, ${address.country}`;
        return (
            <p 
               onClick={() => AddRToLocalStorage(addressText, index)} 
               key={index}
            >
                {addressText}
            </p>
        );
    })}
</div>;
```

Comment: thanks, but when I implement this, I got wired behavior, that I can add only one addressText to the lcoastorage??

Comment: Of course, you can store multiple address by using different key in localStorage. Just pass the index to the function, and localStorage.setItem(`addresses${index}`, addressText) with index.

Comment: but I need to stor the address in array like this [
 "54 some street, some area, London, England",
 "55 some street,some area, London, England",
 "56 some street,some area, London, England"
]

Comment: Localstorage can't store array data, but you can use `JSON.stringify` function when set data, and get data from Localstorage use `JSON.parse`